# addFlashAttribute and holding data

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

How should I hold data from POST request when I use addFlashAttribute?

```
@GetMapping("/collage")
public String paintPicture(@ModelAttribute(value="picture") String img){

    //How to  hold 'img' here?
    //When I send GET I want to see the image again (not only after the  redirect).

    return "collage";
}

@PostMapping(value="/sending")
public String redirect(@RequestParam(value="image") MultipartFile img,  RedirectAttributes redirectAttr) throws IOException {

    String imgAsBase64 = Base64.encodeBase64String(img.getBytes());
    redirectAttr.addFlashAttribute("picture",imgAsBase64);
        return "redirect:/collage"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` stores `FlashMap` (containing the flash variables) as a request attribute. After a redirect, there will be a brand new request, so flash variables will be lost. It seems that flash vars will not work here.

You could use session instead:

```
session.setAttribute("picture", imgAsBase64);
```

and then

```
String imgAsBase64 = (String) session.getAttribute("picture");
```